# ReactJS onclick toggle class event multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, onclick

How can I use this onclick toggle class event multiple times?

```
const [isActive, setActive] = React.useState(false);

<button
  onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)}
  className={`toggle ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}
>
 Categories
</button>
```

Here is the issue in Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-pond-tewk9h?file=/src/App.js

When click on any button it works for all others.

Comment: Put the function in a variable and pass that instead? `const myFunc = () =>` then `onClick={myFunc}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a component for your button that contains the useState.
Else, the useState is global for all the components that use it.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-feather-vj8owx?file=/src/App.js

```
const MyButtonComponent = ({myText}) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)}
      className={`toggle ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}
    >
      {myText}
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyButtonComponent myText="Something" />
      <MyButtonComponent myText="Something else"/>
      <MyButtonComponent myText="Else something"/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is ok.. but how can we add different text in each buttons?

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to pass a prop to MyButtonComponent

Comment: sure.. let me check with my code

Comment: if you don't mind, one more thing: can we call different ID's for each button? actually it is for a collapsible component.. that's why I need ID

Comment: As you passed myText, you can pass the id: `const MyButtonComponent = ({myText, myId }) => {
` and do something like `<MyButtonComponent myText="Something" myId={myId}/>` and `<button id={myId}...`

Answer (score 0):

This is for reference:

Edited answer from [Magofoco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586999/6191987)

Passing button text & ID:

```
const MyButtonComponent = ({ myText, myId }) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)}
      className={`toggle ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}
      id={myId}
    >
      {myText}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyButtonComponent myText="something" myId="tab01" />
  );
}
```